# Liquibase CDI Integration

Tags: java, cdi

I am trying to integrate Liquibase into my application and want it to run at deployment time with CDI. I have followed the instructions at http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/cdi.html but have not had any luck. Here is my code

com.example.dbv.LiquibaeProducer

```
package com.example.dbv;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import liquibase.integration.cdi.CDILiquibaseConfig;
import liquibase.integration.cdi.annotations.LiquibaseType;
import liquibase.resource.ClassLoaderResourceAccessor;
import liquibase.resource.ResourceAccessor;

public class LiquibaseProducer {

@Resource(mappedName="jdbc/mysql-ds") 
protected DataSource ds;

@Produces
@LiquibaseType
public CDILiquibaseConfig createConfig() {
    CDILiquibaseConfig config = new CDILiquibaseConfig();
    config.setChangeLog("com/example/dbv/changeLog.sql");

    return config;
}

@Produces
@LiquibaseType
public DataSource createDataSource() throws SQLException {
    return ds;
}

@Produces
@LiquibaseType
public ResourceAccessor create() {
    return new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(getClass().getClassLoader());
}

}
```

com.example.dbv.changeLog.sql

```
--liquibase formatted sql

--changeset ci_ms:1
create table test1 (
    id int primary key,
    name varchar(255)
);
--rollback drop table test1;
```

When I deploy the application I get the following error:

```
[2014-12-24T08:18:58.671-0600] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [NCLS-CORE-00026] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1419430738671] [levelValue: 1000] [[
Exception during lifecycle processing
org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: CDI deployment failure:javax/enterprise/inject/spi/Extension
at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:234)
at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:328)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:496)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:231)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:231)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/enterprise/inject/spi/Extension
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:412)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.APIClassLoaderServiceImpl$APIClassLoader.loadClass(APIClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:257)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:412)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:412)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:412)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:412)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:412)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at org.jboss.weld.util.ServiceLoader.loadClass(ServiceLoader.java:225)
at org.jboss.weld.util.ServiceLoader.loadService(ServiceLoader.java:210)
at org.jboss.weld.util.ServiceLoader.loadServiceFile(ServiceLoader.java:182)
at org.jboss.weld.util.ServiceLoader.reload(ServiceLoader.java:153)
at org.jboss.weld.util.ServiceLoader.iterator(ServiceLoader.java:297)
at org.glassfish.weld.DeploymentImpl.getExtensions(DeploymentImpl.java:466)
at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:218)
... 55 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Extension
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 80 more
]]
```

Comment: This looks like a packaging issue.  What's ending up in your war/ear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is limited to Glassfish. We switched to wildfly and it works fine as coded.

Answer (score 2):

This is a Liquibase issue really. The Liquibase CDI module is not spec compliant in invoking a bean method in `CDIBootstrap.afterDeploymentValidation()`.

You cannot invoke CDI bean methods before the CDI container has finished booting (or more precisely, you can do it, but it may work (on WildFly) or not (on GlassFish).

The Liquibase update should be triggered by a `@Singleton @Startup` EJB or by a servlet context listener, not by a CDI extension observer method.